# How to pass an array of constexpr strings as an argument?

Tags: c++

I have a file which contains arrays of strings representing some icons.

```
static constexpr char icons1[2][40] = {
  "icon1_A", "icon1_B"
};

static constexpr char icons2[3][30] = {
  "icon22_A", "icon2_B", "icons2_C"
};
```

Then I have a class that wants to be initialized with a reference to these icons.

```
class Display {
public:
  Display(const char ** _icons) : icons(_icons), current_icon(0) {}

  void print_next_icon() {
    std::cout << icons[++current_icon] << std::endl;
  }
  
private:
  const char **icons;
  size_t current_icon;
}
```

I am getting a compiler error when I try to initialize the `Display` class by passing it the constexpr icons:

```
Display i1(icons1); 
Display i2(icons2);
```

I've tried casting it to `const char**`, but the compiler complains that the cast removes attributes.

Comment: You've dodged a bullet here by being stopped by the compiler because the attributes are the least of your worries. A `char**` is not the same as a `char [][40]`, so casting would have left you with a logic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration here is needlessly complicated. Try and keep it simple:

```cpp
static const char* icons1[] = {
  "icon1_A", "icon1_B"
};
```

If you're passing these in as arguments and you need to know exactly how many there are it helps to have some kind of terminator:

```cpp
static const char* icons1[] = {
  "icon1_A", "icon1_B", nullptr
};
```

Where you can iterate through this list until you hit `nullptr` and then stop.

`constexpr` is used for, not surprisingly, `const` *expressions*, as in more complex expressions with operators in them and/or functions that you want to evaluate. It's not necessary here since nothing exotic is going on, this is a straight-forward `const` declaration.

What's worth noting here is that the memory layout of `char**` and `char[3][40]` are *completely different*. In the first case you have an array of pointers, where those pointers refer to arbitrary memory locations, and in the second you have what is effectively a contiguous chunk of 120 bytes, no pointers at all. This cannot be recast to the other form, it requires creating a new array of pointers.

That being said, your function *assumes* that these pointers will have an indefinite lifespan, which can be risky. It's almost always safer to use `std::string`, as in `std::vector<std::string>` to pass these around.